# F# FSharp.Data.CsvProvider, error when accessing rows

Tags: csv, f#, type-providers

I am trying to read data from a csv file using the following code.

```
    let testData = CsvProvider<"../../../../test.csv/test.csv">.Load("../../../../test.csv/test2.csv")
    for row in  testData.Rows do
        printfn "%A" row
```

I get the following error when the 2nd line is reached. ie. testData.Rows :
**"Attempted to access an element as a type incompatible with the array."**

The csv file has 127 cols with headers and is about 6.5MB. The values are strings, ints and decimals and is comma delimited. So I don't see anything peculiar with the csv file.

Using : package id="FSharp.Data" version="2.2.5" targetFramework="net45"

Anyone know what the problem could be?

This following CSV four-line sample reproduces the problem:

```
"Id","Product_Info_1","Product_Info_2","Product_Info_3","Product_Info_4","Product_Info_5","Product_Info_6","Product_Info_7","Ins_Age","Ht","Wt","BMI","Employment_Info_1","Employment_Info_2","Employment_Info_3","Employment_Info_4","Employment_Info_5","Employment_Info_6","InsuredInfo_1","InsuredInfo_2","InsuredInfo_3","InsuredInfo_4","InsuredInfo_5","InsuredInfo_6","InsuredInfo_7","Insurance_History_1","Insurance_History_2","Insurance_History_3","Insurance_History_4","Insurance_History_5","Insurance_History_7","Insurance_History_8","Insurance_History_9","Family_Hist_1","Family_Hist_2","Family_Hist_3","Family_Hist_4","Family_Hist_5","Medical_History_1","Medical_History_2","Medical_History_3","Medical_History_4","Medical_History_5","Medical_History_6","Medical_History_7","Medical_History_8","Medical_History_9","Medical_History_10","Medical_History_11","Medical_History_12","Medical_History_13","Medical_History_14","Medical_History_15","Medical_History_16","Medical_History_17","Medical_History_18","Medical_History_19","Medical_History_20","Medical_History_21","Medical_History_22","Medical_History_23","Medical_History_24","Medical_History_25","Medical_History_26","Medical_History_27","Medical_History_28","Medical_History_29","Medical_History_30","Medical_History_31","Medical_History_32","Medical_History_33","Medical_History_34","Medical_History_35","Medical_History_36","Medical_History_37","Medical_History_38","Medical_History_39","Medical_History_40","Medical_History_41","Medical_Keyword_1","Medical_Keyword_2","Medical_Keyword_3","Medical_Keyword_4","Medical_Keyword_5","Medical_Keyword_6","Medical_Keyword_7","Medical_Keyword_8","Medical_Keyword_9","Medical_Keyword_10","Medical_Keyword_11","Medical_Keyword_12","Medical_Keyword_13","Medical_Keyword_14","Medical_Keyword_15","Medical_Keyword_16","Medical_Keyword_17","Medical_Keyword_18","Medical_Keyword_19","Medical_Keyword_20","Medical_Keyword_21","Medical_Keyword_22","Medical_Keyword_23","Medical_Keyword_24","Medical_Keyword_25","Medical_Keyword_26","Medical_Keyword_27","Medical_Keyword_28","Medical_Keyword_29","Medical_Keyword_30","Medical_Keyword_31","Medical_Keyword_32","Medical_Keyword_33","Medical_Keyword_34","Medical_Keyword_35","Medical_Keyword_36","Medical_Keyword_37","Medical_Keyword_38","Medical_Keyword_39","Medical_Keyword_40","Medical_Keyword_41","Medical_Keyword_42","Medical_Keyword_43","Medical_Keyword_44","Medical_Keyword_45","Medical_Keyword_46","Medical_Keyword_47","Medical_Keyword_48"
1,1,"D3",26,0.487179487,2,3,1,0.611940299,0.781818182,0.338912134,0.472261563,0.15,3,1,0,2,0.5,2,2,11,3,1,1,1,2,1,1,3,,3,2,3,3,,0.62745098,0.76056338,,2,16,2,2,1,3,1,2,2,,3,2,1,3,,1,2,1,1,2,1,2,1,,2,2,1,1,3,2,3,,3,3,1,3,2,1,3,3,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
3,1,"A2",26,0.076923077,2,3,1,0.626865672,0.727272727,0.311715481,0.484983978,0,1,3,0.07,2,0.2,1,2,8,3,1,1,1,1,1,3,1,0.001666667,1,1,2,2,,0.529411765,0.746478873,,5,261,3,1,1,3,2,2,1,,3,2,3,3,110,3,3,1,1,2,1,2,3,,2,2,3,1,3,2,3,,3,3,1,3,2,1,3,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
4,1,"D3",26,0.144666667,2,3,1,0.582089552,0.709090909,0.320083682,0.519103193,0.143,9,1,0,2,0.45,1,2,3,3,1,1,1,2,1,1,3,,3,2,3,3,0.666666667,,0.661971831,,3,132,2,1,1,3,2,2,2,,3,2,3,3,240,1,3,1,1,2,1,2,3,,2,2,3,1,1,2,3,,1,3,1,3,2,1,3,3,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
9,1,"A1",26,0.151708718,2,1,1,0.52238806,0.654545455,0.267782427,0.486962093,0.21,9,1,0,2,1,2,2,3,3,1,1,1,1,1,3,1,0.000666667,2,1,2,2,,0.68627451,0.676056338,,,162,3,2,1,1,2,3,2,,3,2,3,3,,1,3,1,1,2,2,2,3,,1,3,3,2,3,2,3,,3,1,1,2,2,1,3,3,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1
```

Comment: Can you share call stack?

Comment: That is quite a large file, are you certain that the file is formatted correctly throughout?  Can you supply a short sample of the file?

Comment: Does your actual data have missing values that are not in the sample data? I think I have seen this error when I had missing floats coded as strings that weren't in the sample file.

Have you tried the Csv parser? That allows you to do explicit conversions using tryParse to handle strange values, and that way is more robust.

Comment: I don't have a problem when I do this code:`let testd = CsvProvider<"c:/users/nicholas/downloads/test.csv">.GetSample()
for row in testd.Rows do
    printfn "%A" row`

Comment: I can confirm that I have the same problem with simple single column csv file.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue? I just tried to reproduce it with the current version of FSharp.Data (2.3.2) and the sample csv file you provided loaded with no problems, so maybe this has been fixed in the past few FSharp.Data releases.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot remember what I did to get it to work. I might have restarted my VS or something like that. Sorry I cannot answer your question, too many other important things to be concerned about.